# Basic HTTP server implementation in Rust

Tags: rust

I have made a basic HTTP server implementation in Rust. I have used frameworks like Actix-web in the past but the purpose of this code was learning and experimenting. I wanted to work as "low-level" as possible.

The code works pretty good and cool IMHO. It supports multiple HTTP-methods like GET and POST. It is possible to use named parameters in the routes,...

**Notes:**

- This is purely experimental learning code. There is no checking for edge-cases or malformed requests. I kept it basic.
- In my code I have tagged some comments with `[REVIEW]` on places where I think my code can be improved or I have questions.
- Currently everything is in one file for simplicity. But actually I'd put `Routes` in a different module so the programmer has a separate file to define his Route functions.

**Questions:**

- In my code I have tagged comments with questions using `[REVIEW]`. Most of the questions are about better ways to implement something or searching for more elegant solutions.
- I also want to know if there are ways to improve the performance of my code somewhere. I for example use `clone()` in the `goto` function to convert a mutable object to a immutable object. In the route functions I also use `cloned()` to create a cloned version of the iterator to retrieve the URL-parameter values. Can this be improved?
- **Most important**: Considering that we agree that this code shouldn't be used in production. How is the overall quality and readability of my code? Would you consider it somewhat professional or rather the code of a total beginner?

**Example output:**

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080
This is the homepage.
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/welcome/foobar
Welcome foobar
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/welcome/foobar/25
Welcome foobar, your age is 25
$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/print -d '{"name": "foobar"}'
# Server output:
# Name foobar
```

**Code:**

```rust
// Tokio
use tokio_tungstenite::{connect_async, tungstenite::protocol::Message};
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt};
use tokio::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
// Futures
use futures_util::{future, pin_mut, StreamExt};
use futures::FutureExt;
use futures::future::BoxFuture;
// String manipulation (JSON, serialization, regexes,...)
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use regex::Regex;
use serde_json;
// std
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::error::Error;
// Other
use async_trait::async_trait;
use reqwest;
use url;

// Some seemingly unused imports are actually used in the excluded modules.
//mod api;
//use api::ExchangeAPI;

// Define type for tuple containing routes. (HTTP-method, path, fn pointer to route function).
//
// [REVIEW] I have this type defined so the programmer can define routes in the main function like
// this:
// ("GET", "/my/path", |r, h| Routes::index(r, h).boxed())
// This seemed the cleanest way to do it? Is there a better way? Would you maybe use a struct
// instead?
type Route = (&'static str, &'static str, fn(&Routes, Http) -> BoxFuture<Result<HttpResponse, String>>);

// Macros
//
// This macro improves the readability of the code. Instead of
// ("GET", "/", |r, h| Routes::index(r, h).boxed()) the programmer can just
// type route!("GET", "/", Routes::index).
macro_rules! route {
    ($m:expr, $p:expr, $fn:path) => {
        ($m, $p, |r, h| $fn(r, h).boxed())
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    
    // Start server.
    let server = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").await.expect("Failed to bind to 127.0.0.1:8080");
    println!("Listening on 127.0.0.1:8080...");

    // Define all your routes here.
    let routes: Arc<std::vec::Vec<Route>> = Arc::new(vec![
        route!("GET", "/", Routes::index),
        route!("GET", "/welcome/{name}", Routes::welcome),
        route!("GET", "/welcome/{name}/{age}", Routes::welcome_age),
        route!("POST", "/print", Routes::print_name),
        route!("GET", "/html-page", Routes::html_page),
    ]);

    // Spawn process to handle incoming streams.
    // [REVIEW] I currently pass the vector of routes as a parameter to the
    // functions which require the roots. Would be using a lazy_static be more clean?
    loop {
        let cloned_routes = routes.clone();
        let (mut stream, _) = server.accept().await.unwrap();
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            if let Err(e) = process(&mut stream, &cloned_routes).await {
                eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            }
        });
    }

}

// Process the incoming streams.
async fn process(stream: &mut TcpStream, routes: &std::vec::Vec<Route>) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
   
    // Buffer holding the stream in bytes.
    let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
    if let Err(e) = stream.read(&mut buffer).await {
        eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
        
        let response = Routes::internal_server_error().await;
        stream.write_all(response.to_string().as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
        stream.flush().await.unwrap();

        return Ok(());
    }
   
    // Create a string from the contents of the buffer.
    let stream_string = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer[..]);

    // Turn the raw stream as string into a workable Http-object.
    let mut http = Http::from_str(&stream_string);
    
    // Check if there is a route matching the HTTP-method and path.
    let response = match Routes::goto(&mut http, routes).await {
        Ok(r) => r,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            Routes::internal_server_error().await
        }
    };

    // Write response to stream as answer.
    stream.write_all(format!("{}\n", response).as_bytes()).await.unwrap();
    stream.flush().await.unwrap();

    Ok(())
}

// Struct for incoming HTTP requests.
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Http {
    method: String,
    path: String,
    host: String,
    params: std::collections::HashMap<String, String>,
    body: String,
}

impl Http {
    // Generate Http-object from raw stream string.
    // Note: This function assumes that all incoming requests are well formed in the expected
    // format.
    fn from_str(str: &str) -> Self {
        let lines : std::vec::Vec<&str> = str.lines().collect();
        let request_line : std::vec::Vec<&str> = lines[0].split_whitespace().collect();
        
        let method = request_line[0];
        let path = request_line[1];
        let host = lines[1].split_whitespace().collect::<std::vec::Vec<&str>>()[1];
      
        // [REVIEW] Here I extract the body from the request. The logic is that in the request
        // the headers are always beneath each other and the body comes after the headers
        // after a new line (AKA teh seperator). Is there a more elegant way to do this?
        let mut body = "".to_string();
        let mut sep_found = false;
        for line in lines {
            if line == "" {
                sep_found = true;
                continue;
            }

            if sep_found {
                body = format!("{}\n{}", body, line);
            }
        }

        // Remove trailing zero-bytes.
        body = body.chars().filter(|&c| c != '\0').collect();

        Http {
            method: method.into(),
            path: path.into(),
            host: host.into(),
            // Params will be set in Route::goto where we find the matching route.
            params: std::collections::HashMap::new(),
            body: body,
        }
    }
}

// Struct for a HTTP Response.
// This way we can easily define a response and use the string formatter to write
// the response to the stream as string.
struct HttpResponse {
    status: u16,
    content_type: String,
    body: String,
}

// Convert HttpResponse to string.
impl std::fmt::Display for HttpResponse {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(
            f, 
            "HTTP/1.1 {status}\nContent-Type: {content_type}\n\n{body}",
            status = self.status,
            content_type = self.content_type,
            body = self.body
        )
    }
}

// Struct Routes holds the following:
// - A method `goto` to find and execute a the fn pointer to a route for the matching Http-method
// and path.
// - Defined custom routes.
// - Predefined standard routes (e.g 404, 500)
struct Routes;
impl Routes {

    // Find fn pointer to execute the route given the Http-method and path from the incoming
    // request.
    async fn goto(req: &mut Http, routes: &std::vec::Vec<Route>) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        
        if let Some(r) = routes.iter().find(|&&(m, p, _)| m == req.method && check_path(p, &*req.path)) {
            let (_, p, ro) = *r;
            req.params = extract_params(p, &*req.path);
            return ro(&Routes, req.clone()).await;
        } else {
            return Ok(Routes::not_found().await);
        }

        // A route can contain custom parameters e.g /user/{name}. By formatting
        // the defined routes into a regex string we can check if the defined path
        // matches the given path incoming from the request.
        //
        // :param p: Path we predefined in our routes.
        // :param path: Path extracted from the incoming request.
        fn check_path(p: &str, path: &str) -> bool {
            
            let re_custom_param = Regex::new(r"\{(\w+)\}").unwrap();
            let formatted_path = re_custom_param.replace_all(p, "(\\w+)");
            let regex_str_path = format!("^{}$", formatted_path);

            let re = Regex::new(&regex_str_path).unwrap();
            re.is_match(path)
        }

        // Extract the parameters from the path given in the request and make it
        // workable in a HashMap.
        // E.g:
        // p = /user/{firstname}/{lastname}, path = /user/foo/bar, becomes:
        // {"firstname": "foo", "lastname": "bar"}
        //
        // :param p: Path we predefined in our routes.
        // :param path: Path extracted from the incoming request.
        fn extract_params(p: &str, path: &str) -> std::collections::HashMap<String, String> {
            let mut params : std::collections::HashMap<String, String> = std::collections::HashMap::new();

            // [REVIEW] This code works. But I think there should be a more elegant, functional and
            // 'Rusty' way of achieving this instead of splitting two strings and looping over
            // them.

            // Split both paths in pieces.
            let p_pieces = p.split("/");
            let path_pieces = path.split("/").collect::<std::vec::Vec<&str>>();

            // Loop over the pieces of our predefined route path. If a piece
            // contains {...} AKA is a custom parameter:
            // Add the string between the brackets as key and add the value of the
            // path from the request as value to the hashmap.
            let mut i = 0;
            for p_piece in p_pieces {
                let re = Regex::new(r"\{(\w+)\}").unwrap();
                if re.is_match(p_piece) {
                    let param_name = p_piece.replace("{", "").replace("}", "");
                    params.insert(param_name, path_pieces[i].into());
                }

                i = i + 1;
            }

            params
        }
    }

    // Custom routes.
    // 
    async fn index(&self, req: Http) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        Ok(HttpResponse {
            status: 200,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: "This is the homepage.".into(),
        })
    }
   
    // [REVIEW] (extra) How would I implement something like this?
    //
    // A kind of macro to do the following:
    // #[Route("GET", "/welcome/{name}")]
    async fn welcome(&self, req: Http) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        let name = req.params.get("name").cloned().unwrap_or_else(|| "".to_string());

        Ok(HttpResponse {
            status: 200,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: format!("Welcome {}", name.to_string()),
        })
    }
    
    async fn welcome_age(&self, req: Http) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        let name = req.params.get("name").cloned().unwrap_or_else(|| "".to_string());
        let age = req.params.get("age").cloned().unwrap_or_else(|| "".to_string());

        Ok(HttpResponse {
            status: 200,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: format!("Welcome {}, your age is {}", name.to_string(), age.to_string()),
        })
    }
    
    async fn print_name(&self, req: Http) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        // Define the expected data from the POST-request.
        #[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
        struct Data {
            name: String,
        };

        // Make Data object from POST request body. Return error 400
        // if sent data is malformed.
        let data : Data = match serde_json::from_str(&*req.body) {
            Ok(d) => d,
            Err(e) => {
                return Ok(HttpResponse {
                    status: 400,
                    content_type: "text/plain".into(),
                    body: "".to_string(),
                });
            }
        };

        // Print out the name. Normally we would do something advanced
        // like a database query or smth.
        println!("Name {}", data.name);

        Ok(HttpResponse {
            status: 200,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: "".to_string(),
        })
    }

    // [REVIEW] Not all route-functions use the parameter 'req'. But all route-functions must have it because
    // of the defined type Route. How to solve this or supress these warnings at function level without using
    // #![allow(unused)] so the compilers ignores it for all my code?
    async fn html_page(&self, req: Http) -> Result<HttpResponse, String> {
        let html = 
        r#"
            <h1>Hello</h1>
            <p>This is html.</p>
        "#;

        Ok(HttpResponse {
            status: 200,
            content_type: "text/html".into(),
            body: html.into(),
        })
    }

    // Standard routes.
    //
    async fn not_found() -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponse {
            status: 404,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: "Not found.".into(),
        }
    }

    async fn internal_server_error() -> HttpResponse {
        HttpResponse {
            status: 500,
            content_type: "text/plain".into(),
            body: "Internal server error.".into(),
        }
    }
}
```

````
[package]
name = "rust-api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.11.23"
futures = "0.3.0"
base64 = "0.21.5"
hmac = "0.12.1"
sha2 = "0.10.8"
hex = "0.4"
async-trait = "0.1.74"
tokio = { version = "1.35.1", features = ["macros", "io-std", "rt-multi-thread"] }
tokio-tungstenite = { version = "0.21.0", features = ["native-tls"] }
futures-util = "0.3.29"
futures-channel = "0.3"
url = "2.5.0"
serde_json = "1.0.108"
serde = { version = "1.0.193", features = ["derive"] }
tokio-util = "0.7.10"
tokio-stream = "0.1.14"
lazy_static = "1.4"
regex = "1.10.2"
```
````

Answer (score 2):

First of all building your code makes the compiler spit out a bunch of warnings - mainly around unused imports and unused variables. Also the `host` field is never used.

Compiling code should never produce warnings.

##### General implementation

My main feedback would be lack of request validation - pretty much any invalid request would result in either a process panic or an 500 error while it should result in a 400 response.
I'd change the implementation to use a [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html) to read the incoming stream line by line into a state machine that can validate that the current input matches its expectations.

I can see you wrote as a comment that all request lines are expected to be well-formed, but you should practice to write robust code at all times because this builds good habits. Otherwise you end up training yourself to write code that can only deal with happy-day scenarios and that will yield bad results.

From my somewhat limited experience with Rust so far I have to say it makes it somewhat more elegant than other programing languages to deal with bad data and return errors so you should make use of that (like returning `Result<>` from functions).

For example this code will crash the process with a panic if the request line isn't quite what you expect:

```
let method = request_line[0];
let path = request_line[1];
let host = lines[1].split_whitespace().collect::<std::vec::Vec<&str>>()[1];
```

This code should be handled by a `parse_request_line` method that either returns the parts or an error in case the format isn't what's expected.

Processing the incoming stream line-by-line would also allow you to easily reject it with a 413 error based on some arbitrary size limit that you can define.

##### Specific points

1. Not sure why the `req` param in `goto` is mutable in the first place? Semantically speaking the incoming request should be immutable.
2. Parameter naming - instead of `p` and `path` use `route_path` and `request_path`.
3. No need for `std::vec::Vec` and `std::collections::HashMap` - just `Vec` and `HashMap` suffice since `std` is always available.
4. The configured routes are split and parsed on every request. I'd just parse them once into a more complex route type (or provide a route factory so a developer could write `Route::root()::path("welcome").param("name").param("age").build()`) so that they can be easily matched against incoming requests. I'd probably go for a global variable in this case.